# How to nest ThreeJS Sprites

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

Is there any way to create parent/child relationships with ThreeJS Sprites, so that when for example, the parents position is changed, it reflects the child's position?

Below is a psuedo example of what I have tried. No errors are logged, the child sprite renders, but it's position properties do not change as expected.

```
var emptySprite = new THREE.Sprite();
scene.add(emptySprite);

var childSprite = new THREE.Sprite( material);
emptySprite.add( childSprite );  

 // has no effect on child sprite
  emptySprite.position.x = 300;
```

I have done similar in other js frameworks  (such as createJS) so I would think it would also be possibly in ThreeJS.

Comment: Use `var parent = new THREE.Object3D();` What you want to do is supported.

Comment: BTW I did try to use Object3D, and much like the example above, it rendered, but position /other properties of the child spites did not change.

Comment: Can you provide a simple, live example to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: OK, so THREE.Object3D() works.  I was using a slightly older version of the Three library which wasn't working (v59). Thanks for solving my problem.